# Google Drive API - Android - How to obtain a drive file id?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to develop an android app that can read a xml file stored in my google drive folder, the idea at first is trying to open the file and handle the content.

I've read the [Google Drive API docs for android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started) and i reached a point that I'm lost, it's working with file contents.

According to this guide the way to open a file from drive is this:

```
DriveFile file = ...
file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);`
```

Searching I realized that the complete code (that they not include there is):

```
DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient,DriveId.bg(id));
file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);`
```

Well the problem there is that I don't know the file "id". I've tried the id from the web link of google drive, something like this (https://drive.google.com/open?**id=1EafJ-T6H4xI9VaUuUO5FMVb9Y30xyr7OHuISQ53avso**&authuser=0) but didn´t work.

Comment: You can try opening the Drive file picker using the newOpenFileActivityBuilder API which allows the user to pick the a Drive file. The callback of that API call would return you the DriveId of the picked file and then you can fetch the content as you do now. See https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro#files and 'Open a file' code at  https://developers.google.com/drive/android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution i found for this problem was creating the file from the app. Using the class  ([**"CreateFileActivity.java"**](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileActivity.java)) from google drive api demo app.

With this class i save the returning Driveid from the new file in a global DriveId variable.

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e("","Error while trying to create the file");
                    return;
                }
                Id=result.getDriveFile().getDriveId();
                Log.e("","Created a file with content: " + Id);

            }
        };
```

Then with this id in another method i call the file and read it (If i want i can edit this file information from Google Drive Web App):

```
 public void leer(){
       DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(),Id);
       file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
               .setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);
   }
ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> contentsOpenedCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e("Error:","No se puede abrir el archivo o no se encuentra");
                    return;
                }
                // DriveContents object contains pointers
                // to the actual byte stream
                DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String contentsAsString = builder.toString();
                Log.e("RESULT:",contentsAsString);
            }
        };
```

Comment: but how can i edit the content of same file, please can you post some code?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the DriveAPI Query method, to retrieve any information about an specific file. you will need to define a query object as the following:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
    .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "HelloWorld.java"))
    .build();
```

And set a callback function to iterate on the results:

```
Drive.DriveApi.query(googleApiClient, query)
        .setResultCallback(new OnChildrenRetrievedCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onChildrenRetrieved(MetadataBufferResult result) {
        // Iterate over the matching Metadata instances in mdResultSet
    }
});
```

You can find more information on the topic here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries

Comment: This API is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with this stuff a few months back, and still have some code on GitHub. It may be **VERY outdated** (libver 15 or so), but it may serve as a reference point, and it is simple. [Look here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA). Pull it down, plug in, step through. Fix what's not working anymore :-). I've abandoned it some time ago.

Be aware of the fact that there are 2 different IDs for Google Drive Android API objects, see [SO 22841237](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841237/how-to-identify-drive-id).

In general, you usually start with knowing the file/folder name, query GDAA to get a list of objects. Each of them will yield DriveID and ResourceID. DriveID is used in your app to manipulate the objects (does not mean anything outside your Android App and/or device). ResourceID is the string that appears in different forms in URLs and can be used outside your app (web browser for instance...). Look at this [wrapper](https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA/blob/master/awaits/GAC.java) to get some feeling how it works. But again, it's been a few versions back, so there are no guaranties.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive API is deprecated, now its Google Drive V3 and for Query we use

```
String pageToken = null;
  do {
  FileList result = driveService.files().list()
  .setQ("mimeType='image/jpeg'")
  .setSpaces("drive")
  .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
  .setPageToken(pageToken)
  .execute();
  for (File file : result.getFiles()) {
  System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n",
    file.getName(), file.getId());
  }
  pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
  } 

  while (pageToken != null);
```

You can Learn more here [Officals Docs](http://String%20pageToken%20=%20null;%20do%20%7B%20%20%20FileList%20result%20=%20driveService.files().list()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.setQ(%22mimeType=%27image/jpeg%27%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.setSpaces(%22drive%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.setFields(%22nextPageToken,%20files(id,%20name)%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.setPageToken(pageToken)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.execute();%20%20%20for%20(File%20file%20:%20result.getFiles())%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20System.out.printf(%22Found%20file:%20%25s%20(%25s)%5Cn%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20file.getName(),%20file.getId());%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20pageToken%20=%20result.getNextPageToken();%20%7D%20while%20(pageToken%20!=%20null);)