# Drive id only working with using same device

Tags: google-drive-android-api

Google drive file download only working while using only with uploaded device. It's not working when i try to download from other device, that time it give error response 'Drive id invalid' from drive API. I don't know why its happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33356570/5832311), the DriveId is a 'preliminary' Id that changes after the object has been committed. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api/31553269#31553269). Also, be noted that the DriveID for each file/folder is device specific.

- [Android Google DriveApi returning different DriveID for same title on different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668447/android-google-driveapi-returning-different-driveid-for-same-title-on-different)

  > The DRIVE_ID identifier is specific to your particular device, so if you use it on another device, it means nothing. The RESOURCE_ID is unique across devices, so that's the one you need to use for any type of synchronization. See [SO 22841237](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841237/how-to-identify-drive-id).

Hope this helps!